# Get real path of a symlink

Tags: c, linux

Suppose that I want to get the real path of a symlink. I know that both `readlink` and `stat` system calls can dereference the link and give me its real path. Do they operate in the same way (only regarding the dereferencing, I know that `stat` does lots more)? Should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: If you just want do deference the link, `stat` seems like a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) to tell you about the file at the end of any chain of symlinks; it does not get you the path in any way.  Use [`lstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html)
to get information about the symlink, if any, that is referred to; it acts like `stat()` when the name given is not a symlink.  Use [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) to obtain the path name stored in the symlink named as its argument (beware — it does not null terminate the string).

If you want the full pathname of the file at the end of the symlink, you can use 
[`realpath()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html).  This gives you an absolute pathname which does not cross any symlinks to reach the file.

Comment: `realpath()` looks just like what I was really looking for.

Comment: When using qt anyway, QDir::canonicalPath() was a real help for me (works for files too).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you should use `readlink()` for that. However, notice that it requires that you allocate a buffer to store the dereferenced path in. `lstat()` can help if you want to allocate a buffer of the exact size that is required, as is shown in the example at the bottom of the `readlink()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html).